# Pandas: How to find row in CSV that raises the error: "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am importing a CSV into a Pandas dataframe using the command:

```
df=pandas.read_csv("import.csv", names=["Year", "Month", "Day", "Time", 
"ColA"], encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

However Pandas imports ColA as datatype object.

I tried using this to convert that column to float:

```
df['ColA'] = df['ColA'].astype(float)
```

However this error is raised:

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

This limits me, because I can't run Pandas functions like mean, sum on a column of type object (which I need to be able to). Running functions like that on columns in dataframe of type object returns the error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

ColA contains negative numbers as well.
Now I am wondering how can I get Spyder/Python/Pandas to tell me what specific line is raising the error. In other words how can I find out which line contains what Python interprets as a string?

The CSV contains hundreds of thousands of rows, so looking for the string just by browsing through the CSV in Excel is hopeless. Suggestions are highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The below comment by @Jon Clements succesfully converted the column to type float64. 
However in order to deal with these "non-numerical trouble values" it would ease the process of locating these if they could be given by the Spyder/PythonIDE-console. It makes sense that Python returns the specific location that raises and error. Additionally it can help save a lot of time locating these, especially when dealing with huge CSV-files.

Version info:

```
python: 3.6.3.final.0

python-bits: 64

pandas: 0.20.3
```

Comment: Can't you do `pandas.to_numeric(df['ColA'], errors='coerce')` and deal with the NaNs after? [doc link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: Tried your suggestion: 
    pandas.to_numeric(df['ColA'], errors='coerce')
And the datatype of the column afterwards is float64.

However it still raises the error
    DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Well yes... I was expecting you to actually re-assign the column or create a new one in the dataframe with its return value...

Comment: Fantastic that worked out fine this time. However I would still be interested in knowing if It is possible to get to know which specific line in a CSV which would return errors related to this. Let's assume the CSV contains actual letters like abcd, would your method still work? If so, it would be cool if Pandas can tell the specific location.

Comment: If your index is an auto one from 0-N (so it corresponds to the row numbers in the CSV), then `df.index[pd.to_numeric(df.ColA, errors='coerce').isna()]` should do it... (or re-use your existing column as the selection instead of re-running it)

Comment: Or assuming you've overwritten column A - then `df[df.ColA.isna()]` will retrieve all the rows/columns from the DF where ColA is NaN - so you've got more information available to find...

Comment: I tried both your last suggestions, but the following error is raised:

    AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isna'

I am relatively new to Pandas, so please forgive me if I am missing anything that might seem obvious.

Comment: It most definitely has an attribute `.isna()`... what version of pandas are you using (although I believe it's been there since forever...) . Does a very basic `df['ColA'].isna()` not return a boolean array?

Comment: No boolean array or any array is returned. Just the error.

Comment: Umm... what about `.isnull()`? And is `type(df.ColA)` definitely a pandas core Series object?

Comment: Your last suggestion worked out perfectly using: .isnull() Thanks a lot for the assistance. The datatype of the "new" ColA was float64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried df['ColA'].astype('float64')?

If it doesn't work, try:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

pd.to_numeric has the keyword argument errors:

> arg : list, tuple or array of objects, or Series
>   errors : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
>
> ```
> - If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception
> - If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
> - If 'ignore', then invalid parsing will return the input
> ```